# How to re-use cached images in another view in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, prism

I'm creating an image gallery app using a collection view (thumbnail). I'm using FFloading to get the images from URL. When I click on the image, I want to navigate to another page using the shared Transaction library to view my image on fullscreen. I noticed, however, that when I navigate to the full-screen page the image re-downloads. Is there a way I can achieve this seamless transition? Think Instagram. Thanks

From: Page

````
                                  Aspect="AspectFill"
                                  HeightRequest="150"
                                  RetryCount="5"
                                  CacheDuration="30"
                                  RetryDelay="450"
                                  DownsampleToViewSize="True"
                                  sharedTransitions:Transition.Name="PlaceImage"
                                  sharedTransitions:Transition.Group="{Binding Id}"
                                  Source="{Binding PhotoPath,Converter={StaticResource Key=path}}"/>
                                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference browse},Path=BindingContext.NavigateToDetailsCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>


To: <ffimageloading:CachedImage
               Aspect="AspectFill"
               DownsampleToViewSize="True"
               RetryCount="5"
               FadeAnimationEnabled="True"
               CacheDuration="30"
               Source="{Binding PhotoPath,Converter={StaticResource Key=path}}"
               RetryDelay="450"
               sharedTransitions:Transition.Name="PlaceImage"/>```
````

Comment: I'd start by disabling `DownsampleToViewSize`

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this problem on my side.But why do you use `Converter` for the `Source` ?  If it is convinient for you,could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Comment: It works well if I'm using a local image, but images I'm getting from a URI, there's a slight delay. The reason I'm using a converter is that I don't keep typing in the full URL in all my pages

Comment: `but images I'm getting from a URI, there's a slight delay.`  I got an image from a URL,but I couldn't reproduce this problem. yes, there is a delay when loading the image for the first time, but there was no delay when  navigatting to another page.

Comment: On the next page, do you use the URL? is it possible to share what you have.  I'm really struggling

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, I needed to set a hightrequest on the second page